# I have two kubernetes pods using istio proxy. One uses tls to go to opentelementry, the other doesn't

Tags: istio, open-telemetry-collector

I wish both pods didn't use TLS because the one using it, is failing. The reason it is failing is tht my opentelemetry doesnt support tls.  Any idea how to force the other POD to not to use TLS?

As an example, here is the failing one:

```
2024-02-16T20:44:27.819178Z     debug   envoy router external/envoy/source/common/router/router.cc:732  [Tags: "ConnectionId":"0","StreamId":"6709968225738804427"] router decoding headers:
':method', 'POST'
':path', '/opentelemetry.proto.collector.trace.v1.TraceService/Export'
':authority', 'opentelemetry-collector.istio-system.svc.cluster.local'
':scheme', 'http'
'te', 'trailers'
'content-type', 'application/grpc'
'x-envoy-internal', 'true'
'x-forwarded-for', '172.16.105.94'
        thread=34
2024-02-16T20:44:27.819204Z     debug   envoy pool external/envoy/source/common/http/conn_pool_base.cc:78       queueing stream due to no available connections (ready=0 busy=0 connecting=0)   thread=34
2024-02-16T20:44:27.819213Z     debug   envoy pool external/envoy/source/common/conn_pool/conn_pool_base.cc:291 trying to create new connection thread=34
2024-02-16T20:44:27.819217Z     debug   envoy pool external/envoy/source/common/conn_pool/conn_pool_base.cc:145 creating a new connection (connecting=0)       thread=34
2024-02-16T20:44:27.819310Z     debug   envoy http2 external/envoy/source/common/http/http2/codec_impl.cc:1617  [Tags: "ConnectionId":"3097"] updating connection-level initial window size to 268435456        thread=34
2024-02-16T20:44:27.819322Z     debug   envoy connection external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.h:98      [Tags: "ConnectionId":"3097"] current connecting state: true    thread=34
2024-02-16T20:44:27.819327Z     debug   envoy client external/envoy/source/common/http/codec_client.cc:57       [Tags: "ConnectionId":"3097"] connecting       thread=34
2024-02-16T20:44:27.819332Z     debug   envoy connection external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:1009   [Tags: "ConnectionId":"3097"] connecting to 172.16.77.76:4317   thread=34
2024-02-16T20:44:27.819413Z     debug   envoy connection external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:1028   [Tags: "ConnectionId":"3097"] connection in progress    thread=34
2024-02-16T20:44:27.820496Z     debug   envoy connection external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:746    [Tags: "ConnectionId":"3097"] connectedthread=34
2024-02-16T20:44:27.820655Z     debug   envoy connection external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:241       [Tags: "ConnectionId":"3097"] remote address:172.16.77.76:4317,TLS_error:|268435703:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:TLS_error_end    thread=34
2024-02-16T20:44:27.820670Z     debug   envoy connection external/envoy/source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:278    [Tags: "ConnectionId":"3097"] closing socket: 0 thread=34
2024-02-16T20:44:27.820693Z     debug   envoy connection external/envoy/source/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/ssl_socket.cc:241       [Tags: "ConnectionId":"3097"] remote address:172.16.77.76:4317,TLS_error:|268435703:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:TLS_error_end:TLS_error_end      thread=34
2024-02-16T20:44:27.820735Z     debug   envoy client external/envoy/source/common/http/codec_client.cc:107      [Tags: "ConnectionId":"3097"] disconnect. resetting 0 pending requests  thread=34
2024-02-16T20:44:27.820748Z     debug   envoy pool external/envoy/source/common/conn_pool/conn_pool_base.cc:484 [Tags: "ConnectionId":"3097"] client disconnected, failure reason: TLS_error:|268435703:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:TLS_error_end:TLS_error_end  thread=34
2024-02-16T20:44:27.820761Z     debug   envoy router external/envoy/source/common/router/router.cc:1323 [Tags: "ConnectionId":"0","StreamId":"6709968225738804427"] upstream reset: reset reason: remote connection failure, transport failure reason: TLS_error:|268435703:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:TLS_error_end:TLS_error_end      thread=34
```

When I do a curl request to open telemetry using https I get the same message:

```
istio-proxy@istio-ingressgateway:/$ curl -i https://172.16.77.76:4318/v1/traces
curl: (35) error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number
istio-proxy@istio-ingressgateway:/$
```

Answer (score 0):

OK the issue here is that in the namespace of the pod that was going vai SSL to open telemetry, there was an istio destinationrule that had trafficPolicy like this:

tls:
mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL

I just changed to:

tls:
mode: DISABLE

After that, the pod no longer goes to the opentelemetry collector using ssl